# How to perform GET and POST requestion on same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cherrypy

I am working on a web application where I have to use GET request to render checkboxes in a form and then use POST request to return the selected form data back to the server. But I am unable to perform post request once I receive the checkboxes data using GET request.

I used CherryPy web framework and here is the code for your reference.

**HTML Code Snippet**

```
<div class="wrapper row2">
  <div id="container" class="clear">
    <!-- Slider -->
    <section id="slider">
      <div class="division">
        <div style="width: 40%; height: 100px; float: left; font-size: 20px">
          <form method="post" action="processes">
            <label for="storage">Choose size:</label>
            <select name="post_storage" id="storage">
              <option value="1g">1GB</option>
              <option value="5g">5GB</option>
              <option value="8g">8GB</option>
              <option value="10g">10GB</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="iodepth">Choose iodepth:</label>
            <select name="post_iodepth" id="iodepth">
              <option value="15">15</option>
              <option value="32">32</option>
              <option value="40">40</option>
              <option value="64">64</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="runtime">Choose runtime:</label>
            <select name="post_runtime" id="runtime">
              <option value="750">750</option>
              <option value="1000">1000</option>
              <option value="1250">1250</option>
              <option value="1700">1700</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="ramp_time">Choose ramp_time:</label>
            <select name="post_ramp" id="ramp_time">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="5">5</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="10">10</option>
            </select>
            <br /><br />
            <label for="numjobs">Choose number of jobs:</label>
            <select name="post_jobs" id="numjobs">
              <option value="1">1</option>
              <option value="4">4</option>
              <option value="8">8</option>
              <option value="16">16</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <h6 style="margin: auto;">Select the disks</h6>
        <div id="disknumbers" style="margin-left: 40%; height: 100px; font-size: 18px">
          <button type="submit" id="disk" style="display: none;">
            Submit
          </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

All the checkboxes I receive from GET request will be inside the div tag (div tag id="disknumbers".
So, after selecting all the required checkboxes I need to perform POST request (I submitted the form data with the help of button)
Right after submitting POST request has to be done but it is not working.

**Javascript Code (For GET Request)**

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var count = 0;
window.onload = function() {
$.get("http://192.168.0.109:8080/g5", function(data){
  count = parseInt(data);
  myFunc();
});
function myFunc() {
  const currentRequest = $.get("http://192.168.0.109:8080/u5", function(datapoint){
document.getElementById("disknumbers").innerHTML += "<label for="+"disk_"+j+">"+"<"+"input "+"type="+"checkbox"+" id="+"disk_"+j+" value="+datapoint+" name="+"post_name"+" class="+"check"+">"+datapoint+"</label>";
  });
  if (i < count-1){
    setTimeout(function(){myFunc()}, 1);
    i += 1;
    j += 1;
  } else{
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
 };
};};
```

**Javascript Code for POST request**

```
  const element = document.getElementById("build");
  element.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

  function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("disk").click();
  }
```

I hope someone understood the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's nothing in your example code for the POST that has anything to do with making an HTTP request of any kind.

Comment: POST request happens when I submit the form data as I gave method = "post"" in html form tag. Then the data has to be redirected to the "processes" function written in cherryPy which is not happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your point .. You can use `addClass` to the button + `:not` selector .. See the next example

```js
$(document).on("click" , "button#disk:not(.goPost)" , function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Chechboxes Added From Get request");
  $(this).addClass("goPost").text("Submit Now");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <button type="submit" id="disk">Add Checkbox</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked for me.

Comment: Glad to hear that  @Nithish .. Have a great day 